# Ajax Popup alert

Tags: ajax

I'm looking to do functionality similar to Stackoverflow where in certain instances I want to show a user important info like:

You have 2 new answers and 1 new comment. See your responses.

This shows up in a orangish div on the top of the screen as a sort of alert and has a X on it to kill the window.

I would like to do this using jQuery as that is my library of choice.  Any tutorials or code samples you can send my way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you'll want to combine two concepts:

The first is having a div that shows at the top of the page.  [Take a look at this tutorial](http://www.html.net/tutorials/css/lesson15.asp), which shows you how to place <div>s over top of each other.  Essentially, you'll want your info bar placed at the top with a z-order of something larget than everything else in the same spot.

Once you have it where you want it, you'll then need to fade it in or out.  [This article](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorial-simple-fade-animation) will show you what is required to fade in/out divs using javascript.

Just set the area's opacity to 100% and fade it in when the page loads.  Then have a link or button that calls the javascript to fade out if you want to close it (or do it after a certain time).